# Xamarin.Forms (UWP and Android) directory selection outside of AppData

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, directory, uwp-xaml

I've been pulling my hair out all day. I'm converting my WPF app to Xamarin.Forms (UWP, IOS and Android). I'm currently focused on UWP and Android (don't have an apple devices yet) and I got a lot of the program running but I ran into a huge snag with reading files that are not in my sandbox directory. Currently, my app allows you to choose a folder with images and you can move through them. To test out the reading functionality, I've placed the images into the "LocalState" directory and bingo, my code is working beautifully. Now the program doesn't have a default folder and when I originally created it in WPF, the user would have a pop up and they would choose their own folder but I cannot for the life of me get a similar function for Xamarin. Every time I try something, I get an "access denied". I've seen Android apps allow you to pick a folder for emulators and I'm 100% sure that you can setup UWP to do permissions with StorageApplicationPermissions but I just cannot get this to work for Xamarin.Forms. Please help me!

Comment: Did you try using crossplatform  xamarin FilePicker ?
https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

Comment: I looked at it but decided against it because of how many pictures they would have to select would take forever. Unless it let's me pick once and the whole folder is accessible, this would be painful.

Answer (score 0):

OK, Android first it is easier. You need to setup in the manifest permissions to read and write SD-card. On Marshmallow and later you need to ask for the permission at the runtime (you need to do that from the native project).

On UWP the easiest thing to do would be to set the broadfileaccess in the manifest. Other than that you pointed out to the proper APIs, just you need to run them natively.

In general native code is called by using dependency injection. If it gets too complicated you may consider to create Xamarin.Forms project as a shared project where you can use conditional compiling instead of dependency injection which is quite simpler.

Comment: I tried the broadfileacess (turned it on in the windows privacy settings) and it did not work. Still was getting access denied. I don't like this way either because the end user will have to go and make the change before the program can actually run. Is this not uncommon to access files that are shared between programs? I can't even read My Documents in UWP.

Comment: @dbooher2011 broadfileaccess doesn’t work like that and it works...